# Give the definition of a binary operation for these to be isomorphisms - Fraleigh p. 34 3.18

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

[image]

(1.) In blue:  I understand $\phi^{-1}$ is a homomorphism $\iff \phi^{-1}(3a - 1) * \phi^{-1}(3b - 1) = \phi^{-1}((3a - 1) + (3b - 1)).$
But where did the $(3a - 1), (3b - 1)$ crop up from? Why not just fret about $a,b$?

(2.) Did  you need to compute the inverse of $\phi(x) = 3x - 1$ by interchanging $x, \phi(x)$:$\phi(x) = 3x - 1 \iff x = 3\phi^{-1}(x) - 1 \iff \phi^{-1}(x)  = \frac{x + 1}{3} $. Is there an easier way?

(4.) If I'm right about 3, how can you calculate $\phi^{-1}(0)$? Don't know what $*$ is?

**Update Fev. 4 2014.**

(3.) In red. What's $\phi$ in (b)? Did solution reuse $\phi: <\mathbb{Q},+> \longrightarrow <\mathbb{Q},*>$ from (a)?
or is $\phi: <\mathbb{Q},+> \longleftarrow <\mathbb{Q},*>$?

(5.) To determine $\phi^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{x + 1}{3}$, do you need to compute $\phi^{-1}$ explicitly like I did in (2.) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The isomorphism of $\phi$ implies $\phi(a*b)=\phi(a)+\phi(b)=(3a-1)+(3b-1)$.
   Hence we get $a*b=\phi^{-1}((3a-1)+(3b-1))$.
   If we consider the inverse, then $\phi^{-1}$ allows $\phi^{-1}(a+b)=\phi^{-1}(a)*\phi^{-1}(b)$, so you are right but the computation does not give you $a*b$. You get:
   $$\phi^{-1}(a+b)=\phi^{-1}(a)*\phi^{-1}(b)=\dfrac{a+1}{3}*\dfrac{b+1}{3}$$
2. You can consider what you can do to $a*b$. More or less the obvious choice is to apply $\phi$, in which case you are reduced to (1). In particular there is no need to compute $\phi^{-1}$ explicitly.
3. I believe
   $$\phi^{-1}:<\mathbb Q,*>\leftarrow <\mathbb Q,+>$$
   is the same as
   $$\phi^{-1}:<\mathbb Q,+>\rightarrow <\mathbb Q,*>.$$
4. We want to find $c=\phi^{-1}(0)$, which means $\phi(c)=0$. Then
   $$\phi(c)=3c-1=0\implies c=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$
   Once again, note that we did not explicitly compute $\phi^{-1}$.

Edit: For clarification on (2), recall that we want to find the definition of $*$.
This means we want to know what is $a*b$. There are 2 ways to find this:
(a) Find $\color{blue}{something}$ in $<\mathbb Q,+>$ so that $a*b= \phi^{-1}(\color{blue}{something})$.
(b) Substitute $a*b$ into $\phi$ and look at the result in $<\mathbb Q,+>$.
(Actually (a) and (b) are the same. If you can do it in (a), then applying $\phi$ gives (b) and vice-versa.)

Edit_2: (Moved from comments) For (2), we want to find $a*b$, which we can do by
$$a*b=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a*b))=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)+\phi(b))=\phi^{-1}((3a+1)+(3b+1)).$$
This does not require us to know $\phi^{-1}$. To find $\phi^{-1}$: Let $c\in \Bbb Q$ such that $\phi(c)=a$. $c$ exists since $\phi$ is one-to-one. Therefore $3c-1=a$ and we solve for $c$. This procedure does not require us to obtain a formula for $\phi^{-1}$, the "compute explicitly" part. But on second thoughts I think I was wrong: this is equivalent to "computing explicitly".

Edit_3: (Answering the new update)
(3): Yes, the definition of $\phi$ is the same for (a) and (b). The only difference is group operations in the domain and image of $\phi$. i.e.
$$\text{In }(a), \phi:\langle \Bbb Q,+\rangle \xrightarrow{\phi(x)=3x-1} \langle \Bbb Q,*\rangle$$
$$\text{In }(b), \phi: \langle \Bbb Q,*\rangle \xrightarrow{\phi(x)=3x-1} \langle \Bbb Q,+\rangle$$

(5): Let $y=\phi(x)$. To find $x=\phi^{-1}(y)$ you need to write down $3x-1=\phi(x)=y$, then $x=\frac{y+1}{3}$. Sorry for the confusion. >_<

Comment: @FrankMuer For (2), we want to find $a*b$, which we can do by $a*b=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a*b))=\phi^{-1}(\phi(a)+\phi(b))=\phi^{-1}((3a+1)+(3b+1))$. This does not require us to know $\phi^{-1}$. To find $\phi^{-1}(a)$:
Let $c\in \mathbb Q$ such that $\phi(c)=a$. $c$ exists since $\phi$ is one-to-one. Therefore $3c+1=a$ and we solve for $c$. This procedure does not require us to obtain a formula for $\phi^{-1}$, the "compute explicitly" part. But on second thoughts I think I was wrong: this is equivalent to "computing explicitly".

Comment: @FrankMuer I have made the corrections, let me know if they are not clear enough. My apologies for any confusions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. No apologies needed. Exquisite answer! Thanks a lot again for getting back to me multifarious times. I'll try to upvote your other exquisite answers to thank you.

Comment: @FrankMuer As long as it's useful that's good enough for me, no need to upvote the others actually haha. Thanks for your nice gesture! I'm now at a nice 999 reputation. =D

Comment: Not anymore. No problem. Thanks a lot again.